# Max-Height of Table Data Not Working (div inside table data is causing this??)

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

In a snakes and ladders game, I am making rows using tables. To make the individual snakes and ladders, I am using rotated `div` elements to portray lines. For instance, I want to put a line from the table section containing '4' to the table section containing '16'. The problem is, if the line exceeds a certain height, it begins to affect the height of the table rows.

I have tried to put the `max-height` to a fixed value, but it isn't working. Below is the code snippet which shows that the max height of the bottom row is exceeding `70px`.

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.row td {
  height: 70px;
  max-height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  max-width: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid black;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.row:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.row:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.line {
  background: lightgreen;
  height: 221.35px;
  width: 10px;
  transform: rotate(71.5deg) translate(0px, 0px);
}

.line span {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-71.5deg) translate(-65px, 26px);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>20</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>11</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>
      <div class="line"><span>4</span></div>
    </td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `line` has more `height` than the parent element's `max-height`, thus allowing the parent to expand. There are a number of ways to fix this, but it really depends on what you want.

One solution would be to set the `line` to have a `fixed` `position`, and a negative `margin-top` equal to half of the `height` of the line:

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.row td {
  height: 70px;
  max-height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  max-width: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid black;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.row:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.row:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.line {
  background: lightgreen;
  height: 221.35px;
  width: 10px;
  transform: rotate(71.5deg) translate(0px, 0px);
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: -110.675px;
}

.line span {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-71.5deg) translate(-65px, 26px);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>20</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>11</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td class="line-container">
      <div class="line"><span>4</span></div>
    </td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note that setting the `margin-top` to half of the line height can even be done programatically, by setting a [CSS variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) for the line height and making use of [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc), with something like `height: --line-height` and `margin-top: calc(var(--line-height) / -2)`:

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.row td {
  height: 70px;
  max-height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  max-width: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid black;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.row:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.row:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.line {
  background: lightgreen;
  --line-height: 221.35px;
  height: var(--line-height);
  width: 10px;
  transform: rotate(71.5deg) translate(0px, 0px);
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: calc(var(--line-height) / -2);
}

.line span {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-71.5deg) translate(-65px, 26px);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>20</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>11</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td class="line-container">
      <div class="line"><span>4</span></div>
    </td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```